# How can I group RadioButtons in a table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, radio-button

Following strong and frequent advice here in various answers, I wish to use a `RadioButton` for each row in a table, for a user to select only one row to perform an action on. However, I am using an editor template to generate the table, and each RadioButton has a different name due to the row index being part of the name. Right now I can select all the RadioButtons at once, defeating their object.

How can I group these RadioButtons so that only one at a time can be selected?

Comment: Please provide some sample code as, from your description, I can't see any reason why you wouldn't just take the row index out of the name and put it in the value instead.

Comment: @AntP Taking the row index out of the name breaks the model binding.